# Store tMap flow data into HashMap

Tags: talend

I have a scenario where i want to store data to HashMap after processing in tMap component. 
my flow is as follow :

tFileInputExcel------>tMap------>tJavaRow/tJavaFlex

In tJavaRow, i want to store all my data into a HashMap.

Any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult to do this but it'll be less obvious to the "reader" of the code than the usage of the components.

For readability I'd recommend a tJavaFlex component over the tJavaRow. Assuming the Flow "toHashMap" exits your tMap with the fields "myKey" and "myValue", the code in the tJavaFlex would look like this:

*Start code:*
HashMap myAwesomeMap = new HashMap<>();

*Main code:*
myAwesomeMap.put(toHashMap.myKey, toHashMap.myValue);

*End code:*
/*
whatever you want to do with the aggregated data. You'll probably want to save it to the globalMap in any case.
*/
globalMap.put("myAwesomeMap",  myAwesomeMap);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but how would i take the column name as my key for Map, which is coming from tMap

Comment: here key is my schema name which is i defined in tMap

Comment: let's use another example... using key and Co. is probably harder to understand. Let's say your outgoing tMap schema is called "outToHashMap" and it has the columns "firstName", "lastName" and "passportId". You want the passport id-number as key for the map, then concatenate the name for the value.

Comment: Your main code would look like this: myAwesomeMap.put(outToHashMap.passportId, outTohashMap.firstName + " " + outToHashMap.lastName);

Comment: Sorry but you got me wrong. My requirement is i want to store my flow data in Map as it is. like : i have column "FisrtName" and "LastName". now in my Map i want is myAwesomeMap.put(column,outTohashMap.firstName). So my question here is how would i take the column name from tMap schema. i dont want to hard code my column while putting in Map. anyhow i want to take it from the flow which is coming from tMap

Comment: Hi @PreetyK. Now I understand what you want to do. If you're just trying to avoid hard-coding: I'd recommend you just use a hard-coded solution. You'll have to hard-code the schema anyways. If you absolutely want to do it in code, you can get  the information from the row-structure e.g. **outToHashMap.toString()**. It's a very bad solution but you'll get something like this: `lacoa.sandboxphilipp_0_1.sandboxPhilipp$blubStruct@5ebec15[firstName=Philipp]`. At least that's parsable.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to Philipps answer, I would like to add that you could use the `tHashMap` components. Usually those are deactivated when Talend is installed and you [need to activate them first](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/talend-open-studio/9781782167266/ch01s03.html).

Then it is very easy using them, just add the components as you are used to do. You would save creating code.